# Set custom DNS servers in Google Chrome?

Tags: chrome, dns

There used to be an experimental feature in `chrome://flags` where you can set your own DNS servers for Google Chrome to use ([maybe in Chrome OS only?](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/Nkrwmpymm25)). This feature is now gone (pretty annoying).

Is there a Google Chrome extension that can do something similar to this so I can make Chrome use Google's public DNS servers or my own custom DNS settings?

Below is an image on how it used to look like on Chrome OS:

[image: Radio button group: 'Automatic name servers', 'Google name servers', 'Custom name servers']

Comment: You want it for Google Chrome exclusively?

Comment: @Neeku I'd appreciate it more if it's for chrome. I bet you have some firefox extension in mind, don't you? Please, do share anyway!

Comment: @Franck the image you've added along with the [outdated and a bit unrelated link to your google plus post](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/Nkrwmpymm25) oddly into `chrome://flags` are just kinda wrong. They're for Chrome OS only! Anyway: do you happen to know how to access that  today in other OS'es regular G Chrome Navigator? The point (to me) isn't changing to Google DNS. Rather, as the question title states, enabling us to set CUSTOM NAME SERVERS! :)

Comment: @Cawas I updated my answer below. You can find out more about this.

Comment: @Neeku but that's how to set up a proxy... I don't see how that's an answer! :(

Comment: OMG! My confusion, sorry! Will revert the update now.

Comment: Chrome definitely bypasses the system's DNS setting. We have an Active Directory DNS on a small network. We set the DNS to OpenDNS on the AD Server DNS server forwarders. We blocked youtube.com. IE and Firefox give the website blocked page, but Chrome just happily goes to the blocked domain. It is seriously bad form and, moreover, there is no way to contact Google and get help for the problem, nor does there seem to be a setting to force Chrome to use the system's DNS settings.

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct answer, go to google chrome settings > Advanced > Security

search DNS and enter with customized: https://1.1.1.1/dns-query

[image]

you will get DNS over https

check https://1.1.1.1/help

Answer (score 2):

[DNS Overrider](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dns-overrider/acmhaiiijfheggcaanjlgpampclpbnoh) seems to be an extension that might do what you want, but reading the reviews and the details of it, I don't get a positive feeling towards it. However to set up a custom DNS server, you don't need to do it on your browser. You can set it on your operating system, and maybe that's why Google has decided to remove it from Chrome's settings.

Assuming you're on a Windows machine, you'll need to do this:

> Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center

Then from the left panel select "Change adapter settings".

A new window will open, listing you all the network connections that you have (i.e. Ethernet, WiFi, etc.).

Select the one you're using to connect to the Internet, and right click on it and select "Properties".

In the list from the opened dialog, scroll down to select either of these options depending on what IP version you're using (typically IP v.4):

> Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)

(or)

> Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

**Without unchecking the item**, click on "Properties" button, and manipulate the DNS Server from the second section in this dialog:

[image]

And then confirm and save all the changes you've applied.

I always keep my DNS servers custom, which somewhat optimizing several factors. The addresses used in the screenshot are [Open DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) addresses.

Comment: Re: "You can set it on your operating system" -- Unf. you can find yourself in situations where your IT have disabled the ability to change the DNS system-wide. I'm in a spot where, eg, powershellmagazine.com is unavailable from a typical company box, but *does* work when I use an internal network's VPN. Go figure. If I could change DNS *just* in chrome, I'd be in business.

Comment: *DNS Overrider* has nothing to do with DNS. It just have the worst name.

Answer (score 1):

The [1.1.1.1 DNS Server](https://1.1.1.1/) is a partnership between Cloudflare and APNIC.

Setting up 1.1.1.1 on Windows PC takes two minutes and requires no technical skill or special software. Even if you’re a computer novice

- Click on the Start menu, then click on Control Panel.
- Click on Network and Internet.
- Click on Change Adapter Settings.
- Right click on the Wi-Fi network you are connected to, then click Properties.
- Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (or Version 6 if desired).
- Click Properties.
- Write down any existing DNS server entries for future reference.
- Click Use The Following DNS Server Addresses.
- Replace those addresses with the 1.1.1.1 DNS addresses:
- For IPv4: (primary) 1.1.1.1 and (secondary) 1.0.0.1
- For IPv6: (primary) 2606:4700:4700::1111 and (secondary) 2606:4700:4700::1001
- Click OK, then Close.
- Restart your browser.